My Javascript neural network is not learning as expected
I am making a neural network class in JavaScript to solve a simple problem such as XOR. The issue is, the values predicted after training are always somewhere around 0.5 regardless of training iterations. I am fairly certain that the issue lies within the back propagation of the network.
I searched for references and examined functioning neural network code but cannot identify the problem.
Here is the Neural Network class:

function sigmoid(x) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
}

function sigmoid_d(x) {
    let s = sigmoid(x);
    return s * (1 - s);
}

class NeuralNetwork {
    constructor(input_size, hidden_size, output_size) {
        this.input_size = input_size;
        this.hidden_size = hidden_size;
        this.output_size = output_size;
        this.input = [];

        // Initialize weights and randomize
        this.weights_ih = new Matrix(this.hidden_size, this.input_size);  // Weights between input and hidden layers
        this.weights_ho = new Matrix(this.output_size, this.hidden_size);  // Weights between hidden and output layers
        this.weights_ih.randomize();
        this.weights_ho.randomize();

        // Initialize biases
        this.bias_h = new Matrix(this.hidden_size, 1);
        this.bias_o = new Matrix(this.output_size, 1);
        this.bias_h.randomize();
        this.bias_o.randomize();

        this.learning_rate = 0.1;
    }

    feedForward(inputs, weights, bias) {
        let output = Matrix.multiply(weights, inputs);
        output.add(bias);
        output.map(sigmoid);

        return output;
    }

    fullFeedForward(inputs) {
        inputs = Matrix.fromArray(inputs);
        let hidden = this.feedForward(inputs, this.weights_ih, this.bias_h);
        let outputs = this.feedForward(hidden, this.weights_ho, this.bias_o);

        return outputs;
    }

    train(inputs, targets) {
        // Convert arrays to matrices
        inputs = Matrix.fromArray(inputs);
        targets = Matrix.fromArray(targets);
    
        // Propagate through the network and record the outputs of each layer
        let hidden = this.feedForward(inputs, this.weights_ih, this.bias_h);
        let outputs = this.feedForward(hidden, this.weights_ho, this.bias_o);
    
        // Calculate errors of output layer
        let output_errors = Matrix.subtract(targets, outputs);
    
        // Calculate output gradient
        let gradients = Matrix.map(outputs, sigmoid_d);
        gradients.multiply(output_errors);
        gradients.multiply(this.learning_rate);
    
        // Calculate hidden deltas
        let hidden_T = Matrix.transpose(hidden);
        let weight_ho_deltas = Matrix.multiply(gradients, hidden_T);
    
        // Adjust weights and bias
        this.weights_ho.add(weight_ho_deltas);
        this.bias_o.add(gradients);
    
        // Calculate errors of hidden layer
        let weights_ho_T = Matrix.transpose(this.weights_ho);
        let hidden_errors = Matrix.multiply(weights_ho_T, output_errors);
    
        // Calculate hidden gradient
        let hidden_gradient = Matrix.map(hidden, sigmoid_d);
        hidden_gradient.multiply(hidden_errors);
        hidden_gradient.multiply(this.learning_rate);
    
        // Calculate input deltas
        let inputs_T = Matrix.transpose(inputs);
        let weight_ih_deltas = Matrix.multiply(hidden_gradient, inputs_T);
    
        this.weights_ih.add(weight_ih_deltas);
        this.bias_h.add(hidden_gradient);
    }
    
    
}

And here is the main code
const nn = new NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1);

let inputs = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]];
let targets = [[1], [1], [0], [0]];

for(let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    let random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * inputs.length);
    nn.train(inputs[random_index], targets[random_index]);
}

nn.fullFeedForward([1, 0]).print();
nn.fullFeedForward([0, 1]).print();
nn.fullFeedForward([1, 1]).print();
nn.fullFeedForward([0, 0]).print();
```

